# Joomla 3.3.6 Uncaught ReferenceError: Install is not defined

Tags: javascript, joomla, google-compute-engine

I try to configurate Joomla 3.3.6 in a VM instance of Google Compute Engine, and when I configurate the configuration tab and I do click "next" not work, and the console appears "Uncaught ReferenceError: Install is not defined".

What could be the error? I forgot configurate something?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you first tried googling for this error? There are a few discussions about it in some Joomla forums.

Comment: Yes, I have searched but there is not any solutions that works for me.

Comment: I tried to configurate this page in Mozilla and this works. I think that something it's wrong with my Chrome navigator. If someone knows how to fix this problem, please make us know. thanks.